# Table wider then its wrapping grandparent and no scrollbar displayed

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I would like to scroll a table if it gets to wide for the screen.
The table is wrapped in a lot of other tags. My problem is that my table doesn´t seem to know how much space there is so the entire table is displayed.

I have tried to strip the code from as much as possible in a fiddle demo.
    http://jsfiddle.net/wwgtcLx5/
Here my table is displayed outside the window although I set overflow:hidden and overflow:scroll on the tables wrapping divs.

This is how I want it to work:
    http://jsfiddle.net/dv0tfvst/8/

For it to work I added `style="display:block;"` on the tags that precedes my table. Otherwise my table-tag dosen´t seem to know how much space there is.
This is not a good solution, so I hope someone outthere can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could put `overflow-x: scroll;` on the `<td>` holding the table.

Try putting this in your css:

```
#width_ok{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

I think that's what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/wwgtcLx5/1/

I think the problem you're having is div soup. I have no idea why you have 6 separate divs surrounding one element. Perhaps you need them for something else, in which case I'd suggest amending your example to include the elements you are missing (just copying and pasting the content already there would be fine for demo purposes).
If you replace them with 1 div and give it `width: 100%; scroll-x: auto;` it works. I also gave it `padding-bottom: 50px;` to replicate the spacing you have.
http://jsfiddle.net/wwgtcLx5/2/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This might work in the demo, but in real life I need to put the scrollbar on the div where I put it because there are one more table wrapped in the same td.